# Помогите, пожалуйста, с пунктуацией. Нужны ли запятые?

Tags: пунктуация

В соответствии с запросом (наименование органа откуда пришел запрос) от ( дата) № (_) (нужна запятая?) в рамках подготовки рекомендаций (таких то...) (нужна запятая?) (наименование органа отправителя письма) просит довести информацию до (тех -то...).

Большое спасибо.

Answer (score 1):

**По приведенной схеме** можно сказать следующее.

**Обособление** обстоятельственных оборотов по правилам является **факультативным**, **но в деловых письмах и в препозиции** они обычно не обособляются и однородными не считаются (обороты имеют разные обстоятельственные значения).

Поэтому запятые, как правило, не ставятся.

Comment: Спасибо за помощь!